# How do I use compute() with async functions?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

My app is heavily (and happily) using async functions. However, I have become aware that they are affecting my UI performance because they are executed in the same thread. The accepted solution is to use an isolate.

However, when trying to re-engineer my app to use the compute() function in some places so that the code is run in an isolate, I have been unable to move most of my async code. Here is an example:

```
    // in an async function
    storyList = await compute(_isolateLoad, 0);

static Future<List<Story>> _isolateLoad(int dummy) async {
    List<Story> storyList = List<Story>();
    QuerySnapshot querySS = await _db.collection('stories')
        .orderBy('lastedited', descending: true).limit(maxSearch).getDocuments();
    for (DocumentSnapshot doc in querySS.documents) {
      Story story = Story.fromMap(id: doc.documentID, map: doc.data);
      storyList.add(story);
      await story.getOwnerName();
    }
    return storyList;
  }
```

Generates error:

`exception in StoryRepository.loadStoriesStream: Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.`

I could execute the database functions outside the isolate, but that seems pointless as that's what takes the most time in the async function.

How do I execute the database calls inside an isolate when it appears that compute() cannot contain async functions?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with using `compute` with an asynchronous callback.  It sounds like you're trying to use a plugin before `runApp()` initializes `ServicesBinding`.  There should be an error message explaining this and recommending that you explicitly call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.

Comment: I am calling WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() in main() before starting the app. Do I also need to call it inside the isolate?

Comment: Oh, you're trying to use a plugin in the isolate.  I believe that's https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13937.

Comment: If I call ensureInitialized in the isolate first, I instead get this: Exception: error: native function 'Window_setNeedsReportTimings' (2 arguments) cannot be found